# Only selecting areas not overlapped by another layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

[image]

How do I create a layer that displays only the bright red areas on the map (The areas of the red layer that are not overlapped by the purple or yellow layer)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It is critically important that you **always** include th software in use within the question.  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I know you are using ArcMap.
To select the bright red area only, you may use the Erase Tool in the toolbox of Arcmap.

This is the helping page:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm

It is a two-step operation.

1.
For the in_features, choose the bright red layer, for the erase_features, choose the purple layer, the output layer I would name as bright red layer`.

2.
For the in_features, choose the bright red layer`, for the erase_features, choose the yellow layer, the output layer would be what you want to select.